# How to go over an array result again in order to arrange (by one of the fields) the result into a table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table, resultset

I have to do a "detailed report" ordered by location, provider or asset description
the thing is, although i get the proper result I'd like to display results like

Location 1:

Table here with assets located in that location

Location 2:

Table with assets located in this location...

Same with providers and descriptions...

My PHP and other languages knowledge is limited. So, I thought of doing something like...

Get the array (the full array not just a row) and then checking if the location in `array[i]` is equal to `array[i+1]` then print a `<td>` with the row data otherwise ending that table and then creating a new

Location:

and finally another table with the rows that match that location...

How can i do this in PHP?

Examples:

[This](http://victorianoguera.icad.com.ve) what I currently have

[This](http://victorianoguera.icad.com.ve/want.html) is what I'd like to do

This is what i'm doing in PHP

```
<?php

echo "<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Ubicaci&oacute;n</th>
                <th>C&oacute;digo</th>
                <th>Descripci&oacute;n</th>
                <th>Costo Adquisici&oacute;n</th>
                <th>Saldo a Depreciar de Activos</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>";
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<td></td>
        <td><b>".$row["Ubicacion_actual"]."</b></td>
        <td>".$row["Activo"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Descripcion"]."</td>
        <td>".number_format($row["Costo_Adquisicion"],4)."</td>
        <td>".number_format($row["Saldo_sin_depreciar"],4)."</td>
        <td></td>

        </tr>"; 
}
echo "</tbody>

    </table>";
odbc_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should put all of the data into a local array and then use the local array to deal with it.

so you could have:

```
$theArray = array(); //Array to hold data
$headerIds = array(); //Array to hold unique id of the records
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($theArray, $row);
    if(!in_array($row["Ubicacion_actual"], $headerIds))
    {
         array_push($headerIds, $row["Ubicacion_actual"]);
    }

}

odbc_close($dbhandle);

foreach($headerIds as $id)
{
    //Print the header info
    //...

    //Loop through each item in your data array until its id matches the header id
    foreach($theArray as $dataItem)
    {
        if($dataItem["Ubicacion_actual"] == $id) //This line item has the same id as the header
        {
            //Display the table row data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the only problem with this, is that the tables do not have ID's

Comment: Doesn't each row have a "Ubicacion_actual"? I thought you are grouping the results by this. When I have $id, I am using it as the variable to group the data. So anything with the same "Ubicacion_actual" will be in the same group.

Comment: Did that, got http://www.victorianoguera.icad.com.ve/result.html and using var_dump on $theArray and $HeaderIds http://www.victorianoguera.icad.com.ve/result_var.html ... I was getting an error here: if(!in_array($row["Ubicacion_actual"]), $headerIds) so I changed it to this: if (!in_array($row["Ubicacion_actual"], $headerIds));  Whole code is here: http://www.victorianoguera.icad.com.ve/code.txt

Comment: Oh yeah, I made a mistake with the inarray call. So is it working now?

Comment: Yes! I fixed it and the error i was getting it was due to a ; in the if that didn't go there.... Thank you!